# Java datastore write performance: Objectify vs. JPA

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I ran two five minute long simple benchmarks against the datastore. One used the JPA implementation on top of Datanucleus provided by Google and the other used Objectify for persistence. Each request created 10 new indexed entities with the same 9 fields, each using another datatype. To avoid any effects by the network connection the benchmark returned the timespan between the start and the end of 10 writes.

```
                AVG  Median  10%  90%  99%
      JPA      76.5      76   53   98  114
Objectify      41.1      40   39   43   57
Objectify TX   50.6      50   44   60   69
```

As you can see using Objectify is much faster than JPA. Are there any performance hints for people relying on JPA or should App Engine projects use Objectify instead of JPA? What is the reason behind this huge difference in < 0.99 percentile? Is Datanucleus / JPA that slower by design?

To provide more details, here my Objectify code:

```
// Objectify
public TimedBenchResult writeIndexedAsyncBenchmark() {
  TimedBenchResult result = new TimedBenchResult();    

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      ofy().save().entity(MyUtils.randomIndexedEntity()).now();
  }    

  result.stop();
  return result;
}
```

From the Objectify documentation:

> If you operate on the datastore without an explicit transaction, each datastore operation is treated like a separate little transaction which is retried separately.

So each `ofy().save().entity()` is in it's own little transaction. My as-close-as-possible implementation in JPA looks like this:

```
// JPA
public TimedBenchResult writeIndexedBenchmark() {
   EntityManager em = EntityManagerSingleton.getEntityManager();    

   TimedBenchResult result = new TimedBenchResult();    

   try {
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          // Transaction needed
          // otherwise too much entity groups are involved
          em.getTransaction().begin();
          em.persist(MyUtils.randomJPAIndexedEntity());
          em.getTransaction().commit();
      }
   } finally {
      em.close();
      result.stop();
   }    

   return result;
}
```

Comment: You may want to try Low-level Datastore API for comparison.

Comment: They don't provide the same thing. Google's JPA plugin provides full JPA capabilities, interception of updates etc which AFAIK aren't in Objectify, and that's no criticism of Objectify, just that JPA has them if they are useful to you - all comes down to what you want to do which is most suitable. If you want to push objects to/from the DB when you decide without tracking changes then go for Objectify. Besides Google's JPA plugin uses ancient code that the (not really related) DataNucleus project stopped using long ago AFAIK.

Comment: Even if  I don't know the exact implementation details of Google's JPA for App Engine, it looks like they abandoned the plugin a while ago. After reading the answers, I now think that it really depends what your application has to do. If it is migrated from JEE or you have to comply to a Java standard, then JPA is a good option. Objectify locks you into the App Engine Datastore, but also shows the best datastore-aware implementation. Looking at them from the performance perspective is nice, but should not influence the decision between JPA or Objectify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stop worrying about this. A real world application is unlikely to be dominated by POJO-to-datastore mapping. Pick which API you'd like to spend your time programming in.

One quirk of your test is that because your Objectify code uses asynchronous saves, you're seeing a lot of concurrency that you aren't seeing in your JPA test. FWIW, there's no access to the async API from JPA.

Comment: There has been a typo in the Objectify example: I used the sync API. I think choosing a fast persistence provider is an essential if an application has to respond as quick as possible and that the <= 0.99 percentiles show that JPA is not the fastest solution. But why? Is this the result of the relational db roots of Datanucleus / JPA? So "slow by design". Or is it a missing optimization which is not the case for Objectify?

JPA is sync-only, which is a big drawback.

Comment: First of all, to be apples-to-apples, get rid of the explicit transaction in the JPA code - the comment from the Objectify documentation applies to JPA as well. Second, any real difference between Objectify and JPA will be small amounts of computational work and unlikely to be a major factor in your total GAE bill.

Comment: ...and just to be clear, I vastly prefer Objectify - I wrote it. But that's because it has a better programming model, not for performance reasons.

Comment: I agree, afaik most oft the cost savings can be found in the Datastore and reducing unnecessary writes. But just for the record: I wrapped the Objectify write in a transaction to see if the results change dramatically–they don't. There is still a gap between the JPA version and Objectify. So imho the only valid reason for JPA is using a JEE standard technology instead of a proprietary API for persistence. But even then, the Datastore JPA implementation has number of missing JPA / RDBMS features since it's schemaless NoSQL nature (which might also be the reason behind the performance deficits).

Comment: after working a lot with GAE/J plugin and it's JPA implementation and Objectify, Objectify turned out to be my clear preference. Working with JPA turned out to be error-prone and finding a bug sometimes ended in the plugin's code. Objectify on the other hand has been an easier path from the beginning. It even integrated well into RingoJS-based applications and this is a major benefit for me. Just wanted to highlight this after nearly a year ;)