# JPA for Google Compute engine to access Appengine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-compute-engine, datanucleus, google-cloud-datastore

My application is partly deployed on Appengine and partly on Compute Engine. I need to use Appengine's datastore from Compute Engine. I need ORM implementation for the same like JPA as using Remote API to access datastore will be quiet a task in my application. So kindly give any suggestions on the same.

Also does **Datanucleus access platform** provides anything for Compute engine to access Appengine's datastore remotely ?

There is a similar thread but its not resolved till yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have used [objectify](https://github.com/objectify/objectify) instead of JPA .Its [better](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28843878/java-datastore-write-performance-objectify-vs-jpa) Here is a [GitHub](https://github.com/objectify/objectify-remotely) project to access App Engine datastore remotely. Hope this helps

Comment: "better" is subjective, and this is NOT the site for such remarks (see the FAQ)

Comment: DataNucleus AccessPlatform is nothing to do with Google, and is for the persistence of data in databases (of which GAE/Datastore is not a supported option), consequently I can't see how it has relevance on "Google Compute Engine". It is Google that provide a plugin that makes use of DataNucleus ... but the code that accesses their database is Google's.